# Argument 1 passed to Google_AuthHandler_Guzzle6AuthHandler::_construct() + google calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar

Tengo el siguiente error al querer crear un evento en mi calendario por medio de PHP:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Google_AuthHandler_Guzzle6AuthHandler::__construct() must implement
>   interface Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface, instance of
>   Google_Cache_Memory given, called in
>   C:\xxx\Google\AuthHandler\AuthHandlerFactory.php on line 38 and
>   defined

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código esta así:

```
<?php 

require_once 'xxx/xxx/googleApi/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'xxx/xxx/googleApi/src/Google/Service/Google_Service_Calendar.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('xxx/xxx/googleApi/client_secret.json');
    $client->setApplicationName("Name");
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/xxx/src/index.php?r=agenda/registrar');
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory( 'XXX/XXX/googleApi/Agenda_token.json');
   //$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
   if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
     $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true); 
   } else {
     // Request authorization from the user.
     $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
     printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
     print 'Enter verification code: ';
     $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
     // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
     $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
     // Store the credentials to disk.
        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
     file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
     printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
   }
   $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);


    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                        'summary' => 'Google I/O 2017',
                        'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
                        'description' => 'descripcion',
                        'start' => array(
                            'dateTime' => '2017-05-27T09:00:00-07:00',
                            'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
                        ),
                        'end' => array(
                            'dateTime' => '2017-05-27T17:00:00-07:00',
                            'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
                        ),
                        'recurrence' => array(
                            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
                        ),
                        'attendees' => array(
                            array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
                            array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
                        ),
                        'reminders' => array(
                            'useDefault' => FALSE,
                            'overrides' => array(
                                array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                                array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));
                    $calendarId = ' xxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';
                    $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
                    printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu código como texto?

Comment: ya lo agregue, tuve que ponerlo con una imagen por que se descuadraba todo si lo copiaba y pegaba

Comment: luego de pegar tu código como texto, se debe seleccionar completamente y hacer click en el botón `{ }`